# Prove the following alternative group definition.

Tags: group-theory, definition

Motivation: If operation is change, and there is no change, then there is no operation. Then the meaning of  1+0 =1 is not in the equality itself but in the comparison with other equalities as  1+2=3. The following definition does not use the meaningless equality  1+0 =1, or generally a*e=a. I guess that trying to prove statements using the next definition, matters/problems will arise that do not arise with the standard definition.

Let be the non empty set G = {a,b,c,d,.....z} with the operation *, satisfy the following 3 conditions:

1. a(bc) = (ab)c, for every a, b, c ∈ G (associative law).
2. For every a,b there is c (unique) such that ac = b. (c  is the "path" from a to b).
3. For every a,b there is d (unique) such that bd = a. (d is the "path" back from b to a).

P.S.: the meaning of 2) and 3) is the possibility to "go"/"move" from any member to any member, through the same path (if a->b->c then c->b->a as in the Klein group) or through other path (if a->b->c then c->X->a).

Prove: G,*  is a group.

Proof:

Associativity:

From 1)

Identity element:

Let's prove for every a there is e such that ae=ea=a.

Proof: According to 2) For every a,a there is e such that ae = a. (3)

According to 2) for every e,a there is x such that ex=a, that means ae =ex =a (4)

Let's proof x=a.

Multiply by a on the left, such that the result is some g ∈ G:

ae = ex = a (4) <---> (a)ae = (a)ex = aa =g <---> aae = (ae)x = aa =g (associative) <---> <---> aae = ax = aa =g (3). (5)

According to 2) for every a,g there is x (unique) such that aa=g and ax=g , then a and x are the same, and it's proved x=a. Then replacing in (5): ae = ea = a.

Inverse element: Let's prove that for every a, there is b such that a ⋅ b = e and b ⋅ a = e

According to 2) for every a,e there is b such that ab = e. (6)

According to 2) for every b,e there is X such that bX=e. (7)

Let's proof that X=a

ab = bX = e (6),(7)

Multiply be a on the right:

aba =ea

a(ba) = ea; Associativity

ea = a; Identity element

a(ba) = a; then ba = e

bX=e according to (7)

ba = bX = e; according to 2) for every b,e there is x unique such that bX = e then x=a and it's proved

that for every a, there is b such that a ⋅ b = e and b ⋅ a = e.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Does one need the third condition? Seems redundant with the second condition. On that note, the second condition seems to combine the existence and uniqueness of the identity and inverse. So I don't know how different these two definitions are...

Comment: I suggest your third condition has to be modified to $db=a$ or else $da=b$..

Comment: [I think all examples are of this form](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Right_group)

Comment: Your second and third condition are identical; they do not suffice. Not that in mathematics, “for all $x$ and for all $y$ there exists $c$ such that $xc=y$” is logically equivalent to “for all $x$ and for all $y$ there exists $c$ such that $yc=x$”. There is no inherent order when you have two successive universal quantifiers. Moreover, your proof of the second condition does not guarantee that $e$ is independent of $a$. In addition, you need to assume $G$ is nonempty, which you do not.

Answer (score 3):

Your axioms are satisfied if one takes any nonempty set $G$ and defines the operation $*$ by setting $xy=y$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $G$. If $G$ has at least two elements, this is not a group.